# Delegate and AddressOf

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I have a problem I can not solve.

I created a simple form with a for loop that deals with the creation of n buttons, at the end of the cycle i set to the button a specific sub for the .Click event

```
AddHandler btn.Click AddressOf mySub
```

now i want to do the same thing inside a class. So i created i new class then i wrote a simple method

```
Public Sub buttonCreation(byval nButton as Integer)
```

the method does exactly the same thing as the one in the form, but i stuck when i have to add the Handler for the .Click Event of the button.

I then attempted to crare a delegate but I could not use it, AddressOf accepts only the NAME of the method without parentheses.

EDIT

i created the delegate inside the form

```
 Dim delegate As EventHandler
 delegate  = New EventHandler(AddressOf mySub)
```

then i call my class method and pass delegate as parameter

```
ClassA.buttonCreation(10, delegate)
```

I'm stuck here at the end of the cycle should be assigned to the sub button to invoke when the event. Click is fired, I tried to do this but obviously does not work

```
AddHandler btn.Click AddressOf delegate
```

Can you help me ? 
Best Regards

PS: obviously the method that I want to point is not inside the class, but it is inside the form.

Comment: What code did you write? What error did you get?

Comment: I created a delegate to pass the method "MySub" inside the form as a parameter to the method "buttonCreation" inside my class.

Comment: @Yve updated, thanks for your patience

Comment: Stupid question...without passing a reference to the Form itself or some kind of container, how are those dynamic buttons being added to anything?  If you pass a reference to the form then use that reference to wire up the button click event.

Comment: @Idle_Mind i pass a reference of a container I forgot to bring it in  the example, I can not copy the original code would be too difficult to understand because it does not only this.

Comment: @Yve thank you, i will read it.

Comment: @Yve I think that is enough, unfortunately I use. net from just 2 years and there are still many things that I can not handle completely. Thank you again.

Comment: @Yve in one way or another the links will help me, they always do =). I have not solved yet but I'm considering possible solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the delegate approach, just get rid of the `AddressOf` keyword and place the delegate directly after the comma.

Here's a quick example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ClassA.buttonCreation(5, FlowLayoutPanel1, New EventHandler(AddressOf mySub))
    End Sub

    Private Sub mySub(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        MessageBox.Show(btn.Text)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ClassA

    Public Shared Sub buttonCreation(ByVal n As Integer, ByVal AddTo As Control, ByVal dlg As EventHandler)
        For i As Integer = 1 To n
            Dim btn As New Button
            btn.Text = "Btn" & i
            AddHandler btn.Click, dlg
            AddTo.Controls.Add(btn)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I had tried something similar a few minutes ago but I think I've done something wrong. Thank you very much for your help.